# What is the point of OOP visibility in PHP when Closures and Reflections are available?

Tags: php, class, oop, reflection, closures

Consider this code here:

```
final class TinkerWithMe {
    protected $key1 = 19;
    private $key2 = 88;
}

$class = new TinkerWithMe();

$getKeys = function() {
    return array($this->key1, $this->key2);
};

$oldKeys = $getKeys->call($class);

$newKey1 = 96;
$newKey2 = 42;

$setKeys = function() use ($newKey1, $newKey2) {
    $this->key1 = $newKey1;
    $this->key2 = $newKey2;
};

$setKeys->call($class);
```

Why bother with OOP visibility when you can get around it so easily with Closures or Reflections?

Is there a way of blocking this kind of thing that I am missing?

Comment: Visibility also conveys intent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visibility modifiers aren't iron clad protection or ensure any sort of security or anything of that sort. They're *markers* for how a piece of code is *intended* to be used.

When writing a piece of code like a class, other pieces of code are going to couple with it; meaning you will write other code that calls methods of that class or accesses properties of that class. In order to minimise coupling to the absolute necessary, you will want to keep the *public interface* of the class as small as possible. When you designate something as `public`, you're marking it "for general use". That public piece should then be rather stable and not change, or you risk breaking a lot of coupled code if you do change it.

Marking something as `protected` or `private` marks these parts as *not for general consumption*; it clarifies that these implementation details *might* change in the future or are not supposed to be used by other code "not in the know". This allows you to easier refactor those parts later as necessary and having a better idea of what other parts *might* break as a result. It also helps to ensure the internal state of the class is consistent when external code won't directly modify internal values without completely understanding how it should do so.

PHP will help you honour those markers in the general case by throwing errors when naïvely trying to access `protected` or `private` properties "from the outside"; that prevents most accidental usage and unwanted coupling. PHP is not going to bend over backwards to ensure those properties stay inaccessible under all possible circumstances. If you're really bent on shooting your own foot, so be it. Perhaps you need to do so for testing purposes; it would be counter productive to absolutely prevent you from doing so.

In the [mantra of Python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html):

> We're all consenting adults here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose PHP might be the wrong language but considering how many CMS solutions there are with a large ecosystem of 3rd party plugins, there are some things that are private it would be nice if they could stay private. Goes to show how important it is to not choose 3rd party code lightly.

Comment: If you mean "private" as in "secure": visibility modifiers aren't the right tool for that. Virtually no language will protect you from code running within the same program/thread/context. Yes, if you choose to run some code, you must trust that code. If you don't trust the code, don't run it.

Answer (score 2):

Great question!  I would like to add few more points

The purpose of specifying visibility in OOP languages is:

1. To show what the properties and  methods are meant to do. This is to bring clarity among developers as to how to access/modify the property and methods, to decide whether to extend the class or not.
2. The properties that are set inside its respective class is validated and set to correct values and it is safe to be used inside the Class without checking the property type.
3. It is not a foolproof way to secure the data from modification.

The Purpose of Closures is to throw a piece of function into a variable or another function to perform some activity once in a while. Instead of dedicating a separate section code in global scope for performing an action once in a while and not look at it later you can use closures.

Reflections are meant to introspect objects to know its properties, methods, class etc. It is useful to identify dependencies.
Larvel uses reflection to perform dependency injection of objects.

Yes as you said you can use Closures and Reflection to work around visibility but it should be viewed as a language feature rather than a design flaw as no language can secure data 100%