# Is having the entire function body inside an if statement considered bad practice?

Tags: php

I often find myself writing functions which look like:

```
public function foo($param): void 
{
    if($param) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

with no code executing if `$param` evals to false.

This looks like a bad practice, are there any guidelines/patterns on how to avoid this kind of coding?

Comment: It depends on what you need. It's may be useful if you need to do that.

Comment: yes, it will make your function less clear

Comment: I would prefer `if(!$param) return;` and then your if-content after that, but that's just style I guess. (Maybe return an error code or some exception)

Comment: you could call `foo()` function only in case `$param` evaluates to true. Like `if( $param ) { foo(); }`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti, but in that manner you must check the passed argument before every call! Doing that inside the function you'll wrote less code and less possible mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the function like this:

```
function foo($param='defaultValue') 
{
    if($param)
    {
        //do something

        return true; // or something else
    }

    return false; // by default return false
}
```

By doing this, if `$param` will be evaluated as `false`, the `return false` will be used.

Also, in case your function is inside a class, it's best practice to specify an access modifier (`public`, `protected`, `private`) for that function.

Comment: Please consider that the function does not return anything.

Comment: A function that return nothing I think that isn't a best practice.

Comment: Why not? What should e.g. a setter function return?

Comment: For me, also a setter function must return `true` or `false` in case of success or fail.

Answer (score 1):

### Add [access modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) to function

Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

```
public function foo($param=null) 
{
    /* Condition while not empty then proceed */
    if(!empty($param)) {
        //do something
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what adding access modifiers has to do with the question

Comment: Oki - but since 95% of web development questions are mis-tagged I wouldn't trust them ;)

Comment: @CD001 The question is tagged correctly, and it is good practice to use access modifiers but I ommitted it for the sake of brevity as it is not relevant for the question in any kind.

Comment: @AmanKumar please consider that the function does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the function.
But my opinion is your condition should be outside of the function, for example

```
function foo() {
    // doing something
}
```

and then

```
if ($params) {
    foo();
}
```

it would look more customizable

Comment: That just elevates the problem to a higher function.

Comment: @dev0 Could you give me an example for the problem?

Comment: Well, the if statement doesn't live on its own, it will be in another (wrapper) function, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

If a function is an all-or-nothing condition, I have the `else` condition first - this way, if the `$param` resolves as false the function quits immediately:

```
public function foo($param): void 
{
    if(!$param) {
        return;
    }
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Please consider that the function does not return anything.

Comment: Removed return value.

Comment: Every function, even those that do not have a `return` statement, return something. By default this is `null` (it's not really, but when you do a `var_dump` on `void` you get `null`). So specifying an empty `return` statement is the same as a function doing its thing and returning automatically.

Comment: that's technically true, but a return statement does not make sense in a function that specifies a void return type. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: As the above code is not returning anything, calling only return, it will fulfil the return type `void` in the function signature.

Comment: Not really: FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Return value of foo() must be an instance of void, none returned

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd change this code to:

```
function foo($param) 
{
    $param 
      && (function () {
        // Do code here.
      })();
}
```

but then if I wanted to call the inner function elsewhere, and keep everything clean, I'd probably refactor it into this:

```
function foo($param) 
{
  $param
    && bar();
}

function bar() 
{
  // Do code here
}
```

Then I'd adjust the naming of `foo` to make it clear that it's a wrapper over `bar` and rename `bar` so that it sounds like it's missing the wrapper, maybe something like `action_only` or `action_without_foo`

Then I'd also write it up in the dochints for each function, in OOP land this would be a private method, but that doesn't enforce true privacy either see: [What is the point of OOP visibility in PHP when Closures and Reflections are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352618/what-is-the-point-of-oop-visibility-in-php-when-closures-and-reflections-are-ava), in fact the closure inside the function, in the first example, is more "private" on a technical level

Comment: Doesn't that just complicate things and make the foo function harder to read?

Comment: That depends how you define clearer to read, I define clearer to read as, type hinted, doc typed, function + variable names to declare intent, clear inputs and outputs, do you mean harder to read in terms of encounter foo() and then you need to understand bar() ?